# Magicshine MJ-872 disassembly

Tags: lighting, headlights, led-lights

My light doesn't seem to work well, after 15 minutes of work it starts to switch to lower settings and shutting down. My guess is that I need to add the thermal paste that might be quite old (3+ years). I can't figure out how to get to the LEDs themselves, the only thing I was able to disassembly is the rear driver cover. Could someone explain how can I reach those LEDs?

Comment: Sounds to me like the batteries are dying.

Comment: They are working perfectly with another light...

Comment: For how long?  Another light might work for an hour before the voltage drops below its threshold.

Comment: Have you measured the voltage from the battery pack when the light switches to a lower setting, or shuts down?  LEDs are amazingly reliable, so I doubt the problem is the LEDs.  It's more likely that you have a battery or charger problem.  Have you tried contacting Magicshine?  Is your light still under warranty?

Comment: My gut feeling is battery pack and variations between lights. Have you go another battery pack (A mate might lend one?) to test the light on. If the Light is faulty, its most likely the driver chip rather than the LED. Heat sink compound does not 'wear out'.

Comment: @mattnz this might be an option. I'll try it.

Comment: @rclocher3 If they only speak understandable English... It's quite hard to communicate with them.